# Cant execute sql using SQLite plugin in ionic

Tags: sqlite, ionic3

So I just met this kind of problem with SQLite using the example from this [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/)

Using the example I`m getting this kind of error

> **Argument of type ‘{}’ is not assignable to parameter of type ‘any[]’. Property ‘length’ is missing in type ‘{}’.**

You might get confused of what code did I use so here it is i put the code below into my providers page also I inserted native sqlite in app module providers

```
createGovernmentServices(){
  this.sqlite.create({
  name: 'data.db',
  location: 'default'
  })
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
    db.executeSql('create table danceMoves(name VARCHAR(32))', {})
      .then(() => console.log('Executed SQL'))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
```

I dunno what happen?

Comment: Did you add this `import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';` in app.module.ts and you are working page ?

Comment: @Omsl I believe i did i dont really know what happen, I already have 1 application that is running well with this kind of sql statement but when i create a new application and doing the same thing. the error pops out from nowhere